# Acrobat PDF file is having difficulties. Can't open illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, error

I'm having a problem with and .ai file. It gives me "Acrobat PDF File Format is having difficulties. Object label badly formatted." error.
It's pretty frustrating since I have a bunch of work in there, that I can't access now.
I uploaded the file here - https://files.fm/u/gv7anesw
maybe someone can at least try and open the file themselves and see if the problem remains and it's not just me, or better yet - have a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file with Acrobat....

Save as EPS.

Open the EPS in Illustrator.

Unfortunately, this can flatten artwork and cause font names to be changed. So you may need to readdress those areas after the EPS opens. This is better than losing the work entirely.

The file got corrupt, which can happen for many reasons and why a good backup system and saving often is recommended.

Comment: It sounds to me more like Edgars has an AI file he can't open directly with Acrobat.  But perhaps you looked at the file he uploaded—I didn't.

Comment: Illustrator files, by default are **both** ai files and pdf files.   Acrobat will open **any** Illustrator file by default, the same way Illustrator opens PDFs.

Comment: For clarification, the error Edgar has posted is an *Illustrator* error, not an Acrobat error.